# How to fix WpDataTable only appearing when logged in as an admin user?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a couple of user roles in my Wordpress. I created a table using WpDataTables pro edition and added it to a page. The page can be viewed only by logged in users. The table is appearing when logged in as an administrator, But not appearing when logged in as another user role.

The page is loading when logged in as another user role, Only the table is not appearing.

Comment: in your page if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
  wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
 }

Comment: add_options_page( 'Demo Data Tablee', 'Demo Data Table', 'manage_options', 'demo-data-table-page', 'demo_data_table_method' ); In the demo_daa_table_method function use code in my first comment  for validation

Comment: above code works if your page on backend (admin side). Is your page on front-end? Please show your code.